# Table Header Collapsing After Browser Resize in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I'm having trouble with collapsing table heads in Chrome. When I shrink the window to a narrow width (768px) for mobile/narrow screens and then return it a larger size, the table header does not return to 100% width of the table and the th elements overlap on the left. However, the table data cells resize correctly.

This problem only happens in Chrome (version 45.0.2454.85) for desktop. I've reproduced it in Mac and Windows as well. This doesn't happen in Safari, so I've ruled out webkit being a potential issue.

To reproduce the problem in Chrome, resize your window to less than 768px (or until mobile styles kick in) then return the window to normal size. Example page here where you can see the problem: http://mineralsrefining.com.php53-15.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/development-of-hhs-technology/

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<table class="results">
<col span="1" class="wide">
<thead>
<tr class="headerRow">
<th>Location and
Type of Coal</th>
<th>Feed
Ash %</th>
...
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Eastern Kentucky
Mine A – PCI/Thermal</td>
...
```

CSS

```
body.page table {
border:none;
margin:40px auto;
width:100%;
font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
table-layout:fixed;
}

body.page thead {
background:#ececec;
font-weight:700;
color:#a2222b;  
}

body.page th {
padding:15px 0;
text-align:left;
width:auto;
}

body.page th:first-child {
padding-left:30px;
}

body.page tr {
border-bottom:2px solid #ebebeb;
}

body.page td {
padding:10px;
}

body.page td:first-child {
padding-left:30px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a chrome bug with table re-sizing when the table has table header `<thead>`. If you set in dev tools the table to `display:none` after resizing and then remove the `display:none`, the table renders again and views properly.

I guess as a workaround, try using two tables where you view the specific table relative to the specific media query :

(Table 1) views for media `@media screen and (max-width: 940px)` and another table (Table 2) for screen below this width.

Or eliminate `<thead>` and simply use `<tr>` with `<td>` and identify your first row as header through an id or class.

Comment: I thought it was a Chrome bug too - the problem doesn't replicate on Chrome 44. I'll drop in a bug report to them in a bit.

Comment: Yep that would be proper.